# Objective-C - print method parameters with GDB

Tags: objective-c, gdb

I'm struggling to debug my Objective-C program with GDB. I have a function `- (NSString *)reverse:(NSString *)someString` which I want to debug.

Here's how I set the breakpoint:

```
(gdb) break -[MyClass reverse:]
```

Now, when the code gets to the breakpoint, how do I print the addresses or even better the values of `self` and the method argument? I've done some googling and found suggestions like `po $rdx` but nothing I found works.

How can I solve this?

Comment: if you were running your program within XCode, you'd be able to view your self object, variables and in scope parameters in the Debug window.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: I don't use XCode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clark Cox has written the best explanation of this I've ever found. I refer to this page all the time and have made a local copy in case it ever goes away.

http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/02/04/inspecting-obj-c-parameters-in-gdb/

The quick version for x86_64 and non-floating-point parameters is:

```
first ObjC arg => $rdx
second ObjC arg => $rcx
third ObjC arg => $r8
fourth ObjC arg => $r9
```

Remember, the first two things passed to a method (in $rdi and $rsi) are `self` and `_cmd`. I'm not counting those here.

If you're passing floating points, structs, or more than four arguments, things get more complicated, and you should read the calling conventions in the [AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.99.pdf) section 3.2.3. If you're dealing with i386, PPC, or ARM, see Clark's post, which covers those cases well for the common cases.

Answer (score 3):

When debugging with gdb you can print with po and print ()

```
po self
po someString


print (int) myInt
```

`po` acts like `NSLog(@"%@", self);`
`print ()` acts like `NSLog(@"%d", myInt);`

*you can print more types than int

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `description` method in your class. You can format the values however you like. From the docs:

> The debugger’s print-object command indirectly invokes this method to produce a textual description of an object.

Comment: Doesn't `NSString` provide the `description` method by default?

Comment: Unless your class is deriving off NSString then you are getting NSObject's default implementation which doesn't do much. You can just do po self in the debugger.

Comment: But how do I print the method argument (`someString`)?